# Renamed .apk package still overwrites old filename app when installing on my Android phone

Tags: android, apk

Note that this question does not concern Google Playstore - I am downloading and installing this apk package from my own website.

I have an existing apk file that I can install and open on my Android phone.

Now I want to use the functionality of that old app in a new and similar app, but one that uses a different app name and logos.

I no longer have the old app source code, and I didn't create it in the first place (I subcontracted the app development to a coder who is no longer available).

So I opened the apk file using apktool and located the png image files that are used.  I edited these and saved them in the same location and using the same filenames.

Then I edited the strings.xml file to change the app name text to the new file name.

Then I rebuilt the app, re-signed it using uber-apk-signer and uploaded to my website with a file name that is different from the old apk file.

When I download this new apk file to my Android phone, it prompts that it will replace the old app, even though I have changed the app name and apk filename.  When I install this new app, indeed it does overwrite the old app, and I can successfully open the new app with the new logo.

My question is:  What parameter/file do I need to edit in the decompiled original apk so that the new apk doesn't overwrite the original app when I install it on my Android phone?  I want to be able to install both these apps, because they have similar characteristics, but will be used in different industry sectors (one is for the educational sector and one for the agricultural sector - both are simple charity apps to be used in the country of Myanmar (Burma).

The original apk is at [www.teachersimon.org/simon.apk](http://www.teachersimon.org/simon.apk) and the new app is at [www.teachersimon.org/farmersimon.apk](http://www.teachersimon.org/farmersimon.apk)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to change the package name. Changing the app name itself or the file name won't do anything. But of course, you won't be able to change the package name if you don't have the source code anymore, so you're stuck.

Comment: if you dont want apk to be uploaded on play store then you can do it by reverse engineering the code from apk, make desired changes and generate apk

Answer (score 0):

For this too work, you need to change the package name e.g **com.example.appname** and the applicationId stored in the app's **build.gradle** file. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).